# Using `send` with complex string

Tags: ruby

This code:

```
<% fields_academic = [:major, :second_major] %>
<% fields_academic.each do |a| %>
   <%= @member.send("academic.#{a}".to_s) %>
<% end %>`
```

gives me this error:

```
undefined method 'academic.major' for #<Member:0x007ffd0bb72158>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If these are ActiveRecord objects, you don't have to use `send`. You can access the attributes like that from a Hash `@member.academic[a]`

Comment: Did you read the error message? You are trying to call a method named `academic.major`. Does that method exist? If not, you need to define it. Note, however, that `.` is not a legal character in an Ruby identifier, so you cannot define that method with `def`, you have to use reflection (i.e. `define_method`). You also cannot call it with `.`, you have to use reflection (i.e. `send`).

Comment: Yes it does, @sawa edited the proof that I wrote, but here it goes again: if I write `<% @member.academic.major %>` it works perfectly. Did you down voted, @JörgWMittag?

Comment: @ViniciusMartinson That does not prove what you think you are. `.academic.major` after `@member` is a sequence of two methods applied one after another. It is not a single method. That is what JörgWMittag is mentioning. And voting is anonymous. You are not supposed to ask whether one down/upvoted.

Comment: @sawa, oh ok, I get it. Thank you and accept my apologies if I broke any rules of this community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<% fields_academic.each do |a| %>
  <%= @member.academic.send(a.to_s) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The `to_s` is unnecessary.

Comment: My bad, didn't notice that